# How Implementations can be replaced at run-time for object composition(interface inheritance)

Tags: java

I have came across the following point `the advantage of object composition over class inheritance`. But I often see the following sentence in many articles

> > In object composition, functionality is acquired dynamically at run-time by objects collecting references to other
> >     objects. The advantage of this approach is that implementations can be replaced at run-time. This is possible because
> >     objects are accessed only through their interfaces, so one object can be replaced with another just as long as they
> >     have the same type.

But doubt may be naive, since i am a beginner. How the implementation can be replaced in runtime? If we write a new line of code, don't we need to compile to reflect the change? Then what is meant be `replacing at runtime`? quite confusing.
Or any other magic, behind the scene activities happen. Can anyone please reply.

Answer (score 5):

Think of an implementation of `Stack`.  A simple implementation of `Stack` utilizes a `List` behind the scenes.  So naively, you could extend `ArrayList`.  But now if you want a separate `Stack` backed by a `LinkedList` instead, you would have to have two classes: `ArrayListStack` and `LinkedListStack`.  (This approach also has the disadvantage of exposing `List` methods on a `Stack`, which violates encapsulation).

If you used composition instead, the `List` to back the `Stack` could be provided by the caller, and you could have one `Stack` class that could take either a `LinkedList` or an `ArrayList`, depending on the runtime characteristics desired by the user.

In short, the ability of the implementation to "change at runtime" refers not to an *instance* of the class being able to change its implementation at runtime, but rather that the class *does not know at compile time* what its precise implementation will be.

Also note that a class using composition need not allow the delegate implementation to be chosen at runtime (by the caller).  Sometimes doing so would violate encapsulation, as it would give the caller more information about the internals of the class than is desirable.  In these cases, composition still carries the benefits of only exposing the methods of the abstraction, and allowing the concrete implementation to be changed in a later revision.

### Real-life examples

By the way, I use the example of Stack because it's not purely hypothetical.  [Java's Stack class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) in fact extended `Vector`, which made it forever carry the baggage of synchronization and the performance characteristics of an array-backed list.  As a result, using that class is heavily discouraged.

A perfect example of correctly using composition for a collection can also be found in the Java library, in [`Collections.newSetFromMap(Map)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29).  Since any `Map` can be used to represent a `Set` (by using dummy values), this method returns a `Set` *composed* of the passed-in `Map`.  The returned `Set` then inherits the characteristics of the `Map` it wraps, for example: mutability, thread safety, and runtime performance--all without having to create parallel `Set` implementations to `ConcurrentHashMap`, `ImmutableMap`, `TreeMap`, etc.

Comment: +1. The "replacing the implementation at runtime" part is telling the Stack which type of List to use. Of course, all possible implementations of List (such as ArrayList and LinkedList) have to have been prepared up front. No new code is added after compilation.

Answer (score 3):

There are two strong reasons to prefer composition over inheritance:

- Avoids combinatorial explosions in class hierarchy.
- Can be modified at run-time

Let's say that you are writing an ordering system for a pizza parlor. You would almost certainly have a class Pizza...

```
public class Pizza {
    public double getPrice() { return BASE_PIZZA_PRICE; }
}
```

And, all else being equal, the pizza parlor probably sells a lot of pepperoni pizza. You can use inheritance for this - PepperoniPizza satisfies an "is-a" relationship with pizza, so that sounds valid.

```
public class PepperoniPizza extends Pizza {
    public double getPrice() { return super.getPrice() + PEPPERONI_PRICE; }
}
```

Okay, so far so good, right? But you can probably see that things we haven't considered. What if a customer wants pepperoni and mushrooms, for instance? Well, we can add a PepperoniMushroomPizza class. Already we have a problem - should PepperoniMushroomPizza extend Pizza, PepperoniPizza, or MushroomPizza?

But things get even worse. Let's say our hypothetical pizza parlor offers sizes Small, Medium, and Large. And crust varies too - they offer a thick, thin, and regular crust. If we are just using inheritance, suddenly we have classes like MediumThickCrustPepperoniPizza, LargeThinCrustMushroomPizza, SmallRegularCrustPepperoniAndMushroomPizza, et cetera...

```
public class LargeThinCrustMushroomPizza extends ThinCrustMushroomPizza {
    // This is not good!
}
```

In short, **using inheritance to handle diversity along multiple axes causes a combinatorial explosion in the class hierarchy.**

The second problem (modification at run-time) derives from this as well. Suppose that a customer looks at the price of their LargeThinCrustMushroomPizza, gawks, and decides they'd rather get a MediumThinCrustMushroomPizza instead? Now you are stuck making a whole new object just to change that one attribute!

This is where composition comes in. We observe that a "pepperoni pizza" does indeed have an "is-a" relationship with Pizza, but it also satisfies a "has-a" relationship with Pepperoni. And it also satisfies "has-a" relationships with crust type, and size. So you re-define Pizza using composition:

```
public class Pizza { 
    private List<Topping> toppings;
    private Crust crust;
    private Size size;

    //...omitting constructor, getters, setters for brevity...

    public double getPrice() {
        double price = size.getPrice();
        for (Topping topping : toppings) {
            price += topping.getPriceAtSize(size);
        }
        return price;
    }
}
```

With this composition-based Pizza, the customer can choose a smaller size (`pizza.setSize(new SmallSize())`) and the price (`getPrice()`) will respond appropriately - that is, **the run-time behavior of the method may vary according to the run-time composition of the object.**

This is not to say that inheritance is bad. But where it is possible to use composition instead of inheritance to express a diversity of objects (like pizzas), composition should usually be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers speak a bit about this, but I thought that an example of **how the behaviour can change at runtime** would be helpfull. Suppose you have a interface `Printer`:

```
interface Printer {
    void print(Printable printable);
}

class TestPrinter implements Printer {

    public void print(Printable printable) {
        // set an internal state that can be checked later in a test
    }

}

class FilePrinter implements Printer {

    public void print(Printable printable) {
        // Do stuff to print the printable to a file
    }
}

class NetworkPrinter implements Printer {

    public void print(Printable printable) {
        // Connects to a networked printer and tell it to print the printable
    }
}
```

All of the Printer classes can now be used for different purposes. `TestPrinter` can be used as a mock or stubb when we run tests. `FilePrinter` and `NetworkPrinter` each handle a specific case when printing. So assume we have a UI widget where the user can press a button to print something:

```
class PrintWidget {
    // A collection of printers that keeps track of which printer the user has selected.
    // It could contain a FilePrinter, NetworkPrinter and any other object implementing the
    // Printer interface
    private Selectable<Printer> printers; 

    // A reference to a printable object, could be a document or image or something
    private Printable printable;

    public void onPrintButtonPressed() {
        Printer printer = printers.getSelectedPrinter();
        printer.print(printable);
    }

    // other methods 
}
```

Now at runtime when the user selects another printer and presses the a print button the `onPrintButtonPressed` method gets called and the selected `Printer` used.

Answer (score 0):

That is the Polymorphism  which is the core concept of OOP.

It means ‘**a state of having many shapes**’ or ‘the capacity to take on different forms’. When applied to object oriented programming languages like Java, it describes a language’s ability to process objects of various types and classes through a single, uniform interface.

As mark said List is a Uniform interface and its Different implementations are like `ArrayList`.....etc

Comment: Actually, if we change the implementation, dont we need to compile the code before running? So how at runtime we can change the implmentations. With class inhertiance(unlike interface inheritance), implementation inherited from a parent class cannot be changed at runtime, since it is done statically at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting to answer. I am not sure whether you have used factory pattern or not. But if yo have then understanding this with that example should be good. Let me try to put it here:
Suppose you have a parent class called Pet as defined here
package com.javapapers.sample.designpattern.factorymethod;

```
//super class that serves as type to be instantiated for factory method pattern
public interface Pet {

 public String speak();

}
```

And there are few subclasses such as Dog, Duck etc, sample here:

```
package com.javapapers.sample.designpattern.factorymethod;

//sub class 1 that might get instantiated by a factory method pattern
public class Dog implements Pet {

 public String speak() {
 return "Bark bark...";
 }
}

package com.javapapers.sample.designpattern.factorymethod;

//sub class 2 that might get instantiated by a factory method pattern
public class Duck implements Pet {
 public String speak() {
 return "Quack quack...";
 }
}
```

And there is a factory class  which returns you a Pet depending on the input type, sample here:

```
package com.javapapers.sample.designpattern.factorymethod;

//Factory method pattern implementation that instantiates objects based on logic
public class PetFactory {

 public Pet getPet(String petType) {
 Pet pet = null;

 // based on logic factory instantiates an object
 if ("bark".equals(petType))
 pet = new Dog();
 else if ("quack".equals(petType))
 pet = new Duck();
 return pet;
 }
}
```

Now lets see how at the run time we can have different kind of Pets created depending on the input, sample here

```
//using the factory method pattern
public class SampleFactoryMethod {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // creating the factory
        PetFactory petFactory = new PetFactory();

        System.out.println("Enter a pets language to get the desired pet");
        String input = "";

        try {
            BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            input = bufferRead.readLine();



            // factory instantiates an object
            Pet pet = petFactory.getPet(input);

            // you don't know which object factory created
            System.out.println(pet.speak());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Now if you run the program for different kind of inputs such as "bark" or "quack", you will get a differnt pet. You can change the above program to take different inputs and create different Pets.

Here it answers your question that without changing the code, just depending on type of input you get different behavioral pets.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

> How the implementation can be replaced in runtime?

Let's use some code example to brighten the day (a loop that reads a new line everytime, and reprint all lines read so far):

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(); // chose first "implementation"

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while (true) {
    String line = br.readLine(); // do something like read input from the user
    myCounter.resetChronometer(); // hypothetical time counter

    myList.add(line); // add the line (make use my "implementation")
    // and then do some final work, like printing...
    for(String s: myList) {
        System.out.println(s); // print it all...
    }

    //But, hey, I'm keeping track of the time:
    myCounter.stopChronometer();
    if (myCounter.isTimeTakenTooLong())
        // this "implementation" is too slow! I want to replace it.
        // I WILL replace it at runtime (no recompile, not even stopping)
        List<String> swapList = myList; // just to keep track...

        myList = new LinkedList<String>(); // REPLACED implementation! (!!!) <---

        myList.addAll(swapList); // so I don't lose what I did up until now

        // from now on, the loop will operate with the 
        // new implementation of the List<String>
        // was using the ArrayList implementation. Now will use LinkedList
    }
}
```

Just as you said: ***This is [only] possible because objects [***`myList`***] are accessed only through their interfaces (***`List<String>`***)***. (If we declared `myList` as `ArrayList<String> myList`, this would never be possible...)